# where can i find the last run time of a job in control - m?

Tags: statistics, timestamp, runtime, jobs, control-m

I am new to Control M and would like to find out where can i find the last run time of a job in control - m. I have checked in the synopsis and Details tab and it is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If it is in monitoring: right click, more analisys windows -> statistics

Comment: Use the ctmruninf utility on the Control-M Server.